# C++ write into a file and then read it

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

Now I am working on a small c++ fstream example. What I want to do is to write a number into a file and then read that number from file. Below is my code. The output is not what I expect, however I don't know what's wrong with the code. Can someone help me?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  ofstream outfile("input.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
  int a = 1;
  outfile.write((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
  outfile.close();

  ifstream infile("input.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
  infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
  long size = infile.tellg();
  infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);
  infile.close();

  int aa;//
  infile.read((char*)&aa, sizeof(int));

  cout << aa << endl;
  cout << size << endl;
  infile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

My expected output is: aa 1, size, 4. But the actual output is:

```
32765
4
```

The value of aa is wrong. Can someone help me?  Thank you!

Comment: You are closing the file before you read from it.

Comment: @NikolaBenes Got it! Thank you! It seems I made a ridiculous mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

infile.close(); is written 2 times, take down the first one, no need to close before it even read the file, as Nikola comment.